# No such module 'Swifter' error on Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode

I would like using the Swifter in Xcode 9 with Swift language. I installed the swifter pods to my project. I wrote to my top of `ViewController.swift` this line

```
import Swifter
```

and the Xcode 9 is send me this error:

> No such module 'Swifter'

[image: Project's map]  [image: Build]

Here is my project's map and results of build.

What is the problem(s)?

Sorry, because my Swift/Xcode knowledge is very pure as my English :)

Comment: Did you try to build your app?

Comment: kiwisip, of course, but this problem still standing

Comment: if your app builds than there is no problem.. it's just that Xcode indexing is slow, after a while it will disappear

Comment: So, this problem is still a two days :(
I attached my project's map to my question and I'm not sure why have three red line in this map.

Comment: what's your swift version is it 3 or 4 ? use pod update and build again.

Comment: Dear MAhipal! I using Swift 4. And after I see the error messages from build, I thinked from same idea too, like You. So, I don't know, how to set SWIFT_VERSION to Swift 3, but I will find it and trying to using this server. Thanks for your idea!

Comment: @MAhipalSing! Thanks for your very usefull advice! Set to 3.2 Swift is solved my problem! @kiwisip! After settig of course I wait for indexing, because xCode first not found the Swifter import. Thanks for your help!